# Trying to get the correct results when adding two numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add two numbers inside an array one is decimal number the other one is the whole number but when do addition I get wrong results, for example, 4+4.5 I get 8 instead of 8.5;

```
       let a = [1.2,2,"+",4,5,6]

       let c = a.slice(0,a.indexOf("+")).join("")

       let v = a.slice(a.indexOf("+")+1).join("")

       console.log(c,v)

       console.log(parseInt(c)+parseInt(v))
```

Comment: `parseInt` returns an integer ...

Comment: use parseFloat() instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behavior with parseInt

You can use ParseFloat instead.

```
let a = [1.2,2,"+",4,5,6]

let c = a.slice(0,a.indexOf("+")).join("")

let v = a.slice(a.indexOf("+")+1).join("")

console.log(c,v)

console.log(parseFloat(c)+parseFloat(v))
```